# Qt how to display please wait dialog whilst socket is waiting for response?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a function that makes an http request, it can take some time for the server to respond.  During the wait time I would like to display a please wait dialog to the user.

I have tried creating the please wait dialog and then sending the http request to the server.  The please wait dialog returns instantly, no error and nothing displayed, the http request is then made but no please wait dialog is displayed.

If I do not perform the http request and allow execution to continue the dialog is displayed.

I think maybe the solution would be to create the please wait dialog in a new thread ?

My class, clsAlert is derived from clsDialog, in the constructor:

```
    clsAlert::clsAlert(QString strText, QWidget* pParent, bool blnAutoCleanup) : QDialog(pParent), ui(new Ui::clsAlert) {
        ui->setupAlert(this);
        ui->lblText->setText(strText);
        ... set-up geometry ...
        show();
    }
```

Usage example:

```
    clsAlert* pPW = new clsAlert(clsAlert::mscszPleaseWait,mpParent);
    int intServer = intCreateSocket(szDestURL, pOutbio);
    ... a lot more source ...
    pPW->cleanup();
```

Comment: Show us some code! How were you making the dialog appear before?

Comment: @SPlatten: Maybe you have to learn the difference between `exec()` and `show()`, but this might be only guesswork.

Comment: @Aleph0, exec is a blocking version of show, why would I want that?  It would prevent my process from carrying on.

Comment: @SPlatten: Your other process should be doing it work in another thread. If it is finished it should send a signal, which closes the dialog. In that way your GUI will stay responsive.

Comment: @Aleph0, that's not really a justification for using exec or show and doesn't explain why the dialog isn't showing.

Comment: @SPlatten: Did you created the dialog on the stack or with new? It's hard to give an answer with so little posted code here.

Comment: @Aleph0, with new, I'll edit my question to show

Comment: @SPlatten: Did you tried to use `show()` outside of the constructor? Like `dialog->show()`.

Comment: @Aleph0, I have a timer which updates an elapsed label thats visible in the dialog, I have just moved the show call to the timer slot, when show is called a boolean flag is set to prevent it being called again.  Just tried it, no difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195532/discussion-between-aleph0-and-splatten).

Comment: Think of the main thread as the GUI thread. You should never move GUI stuff to a new thread, instead you should move the heavy work to a new thread. Your GUI thread needs to be able to process events to work properly. If you block the event loop with some heavy processing, your GUI will freeze.

Comment: @thuga, that sounds reasonable, I will try creating worker threads for my http class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I fixed this in my case by adding a call to:

```
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
```

Immediately after my call to:

```
    show();
```